# Laravel blade, how to use custom function name in onclick?

Tags: php, laravel

As you can see the code below, i'm trying to use custom function name base on the variable string `$value[2]['got_error_here']`. Assume the content of the variable is `MyFunction`. The error display `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'got_error_here' (T_STRING)`. How to solve this?

**View**

```
{!! is_array($value[2]) ? '<td><a onclick="{{ $value[2]['got_error_here'] }}"><b>Test</b></a></td>' : '<td>Test2</td>' !!}
```

**The Array Content**

[image]

Comment: What is in `$value[2]` ?

Comment: $value[2]['got_error_here'] will look for a index  name "got_error_here" is $value[2]; do your array has something like this;

Comment: @Luke updated my question

Comment: I a really not sure why i got downvoted without any reason

Comment: Do you check my answer? I think it's just syntax error.

Comment: @SangNguyen i just commented on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to

```
{!! is_array($value[2]) ? '<td><a onclick="' . $value[2]['got_error_here'] . '"><b>Test</b></a></td>' : '<td>Test2</td>' !!}
```

Comment: oh wow! this really works! now i have another problem, how do I put `()` after the variable?

Comment: Add after it :D 

`<a onclick="' . $value[2]['got_error_here'] . '()">`

Comment: works perfectly! straight forward answer! i wish i could give you 10 upvotes, thanks